# Using copy with setter?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I wonder if I can just check something that I have not tried before, does this seem ok, bit of a simple question but I wanted to make sure I was understanding things. All the components of CCLocation comply to NSCopying so I am assuming that masterLocation is a deepCopy, dulicate CLLocation with duplicate iVars.

```
        CLLocation *tempLocation = [lastGoodLocation copy];
        [self setMasterLocation:tempLocation];
        [tempLocation release];
```

and could I replace it with

```
        [self setMasterLocation:[[lastGoodLocation copy] autorelease]];
```

Master location is defined as:

```
        @property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocation *masterLocation;
```

**EDIT:**

So I could do:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) CLLocation *masterLocation;
[self setMasterLocation: lastGoodLocation];
```

Comment: You could even declare your property a copy property if the setter must always receive a copy.

Comment: Do you fancy pasting that as an answer @BoltClock, its a good answer?

Comment: ssteinberg has already posted it as one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

```
@property (nonatomic, copy)
```

as well, as BoltClock said.

Comment: And there is no need for -autorelease since it's going to be ratained on the object level.

Comment: copy returns a retained object; without the autorelease, it'll leak.

Comment: Indeed, either autorelease or release. Both examples as posted by fuzzygoat are correct.